# -bash: export: ''not a valid identifier when logging into terminal

Tags: path, rhel-6

Hi Whenever I log into the terminal I get the following error

-bash: export: `/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/nz/bin': not a valid identifier

I am logging in through the root user, and the export variable is $PATH

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have the command

```
export $PATH
```

(or something like it) in one of your initialization files (`.profile`, `.bashrc`, etc.) 
Find it and change it, perhaps to

```
export PATH
```

(note: no `$`) or comment it out and see if anything breaks.

Comment: Some one had edited the /etc/profile file and did export $PATH.